# Coldfusion / MySQL - Subquery output?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Apologies for the poorly-phrased questions - wasn't quite sure how best to phrase it!

I'll start with my query as it currently stands;

```
<cfquery name="getmessages">
    SELECT p.*, u.bgid, u.displayname, u.companyName, (SELECT COUNT(projectid)      
        FROM projectmessages WHERE projectid='#pid#') AS msgcount
    FROM projectmessages p
    LEFT JOIN users u ON p.msgCreator=u.bgid
    WHERE p.projectid='#pid#'
    ORDER BY msgID DESC
    LIMIT 10
</cfquery>
```

That simply outputs messages relating to a specific project.  However, the author of each message may have also uploaded any number of file attachments - which are recorded in a separate table called 'projectfiles' - a unique ID (msgUUID) links both the file record and the message record.

What I'd like to do here is twofold - firstly amend the above query to also return the list of files (fileid, filename) attached to each message if any, and also include these in my cfoutput.

I could of course simply add a cfquery within my cfoutput of 'getmessages', but that seems inefficient, so I've convinced myself there must be something more effective.

I'm aware that I can do a left join to look for 'a file', but I'm stumped at how it would handle instances of multiple files (though that is perhaps more of a case of how I handle it at the cfoutput point?).

Comment: You can do this in the query. When you output make sure the query is ordered by the column you want to group on and use the group attribute of cfoutput to control your output.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'd totally overlooked that - works a treat! (I added the left join  to the projectfiles table, then another cfoutput within the main cfoutput so that it would loop through the files - for the benefit of anyone else searching)

Comment: Glad you figured it out. It's one of the most underutilized features of ColdFusion. Makes things like this so incredibly easy.